# how to create a zkteco custom report

Tags: report, zkteco

I want to create a custom report in zkteco attendance software. If I open a report (eg: Daily Attendance Report) using the Report Designer option of the software, I can see there are lot of variables, functions and data elements but I don't know how to work with them. I searched a lot in the internet but could not find documentation of these variables and functions and how to use them in designing a report.

Does anyone know any tutorial link of descriptions of those variables or functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the already available reports by clicking the Report Designer.
Note: Possible changes (Change Font/Positioning/Apply some format functions/Add few more columns of query result)

1. Double click any field in the Designer.
2. Apply some basic format functions - Like Date format change below:
   [Snapshot from my customized software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkRhN.jpg)
3. Couple of already available variables can be added like: Line#, ReportGenerationTime etc.
4. Save the designer (File is saved in Installation_Direcrtory/attdaily.rpt)

***Important:*** There is no way to change the query which is populating the Data (I am trying to find the compatible crystal reports version to modify the .rpt files - i-e to change the query for Data)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you make a whole column for individual month attendance report? Please read this thread, I posted it two days ago: https://superuser.com/questions/1645109/how-to-make-columns-for-whole-month-in-rpt-of-zkteco

Comment: I think you've done it correctly, just add 20 more entries downwards to make it a full month. Get help from an already available (Daily Attendance) report! It is just that in that report data is row-wise.

Comment: If you analyze the row-wise Daily Attendance Report, you will find that formula is calculated like below to get attendance of 10 days from the Starting Date : BeginDate | BeginDate+1 | BeginDate+2 | BeginDate+3 .......... BeginDate+9. From the 2nd row, it continues from the BeginDate+10. Now If I move the row-wise objects to columnwise and create more 20 entries up to BeginDate+30, and set the sub-report to two columns layout (plz see the picture there), then there should be attendance of 1st date of next month from the 2nd column, but it is not happening, 2nd col is showing from BeginDate+10.